# How to use Sendmessage in C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I got the hwnd = FindWindow(""); but how to do Sendmessage with mouse clicks with this window ??
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage
    (IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

For usage information look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx
Generaly you must only call this function with good arguments, to know what arguments you need you must look at msdn.

Comment: Not very helpful for me, because I've already read those pages but I don't get it.

Comment: Read Petzold's Programming Windows first.

Comment: @user 512205 You should edit you question with me information on what exactly you want to accomplish and what if is you don't understand if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to simulate mouse clicks using SendMessage?

This is a duplicate question to this one: [Using SendMessage for Simulating User Mouse Clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792130/using-sendmessage-for-simulating-user-mouse-clicks).

The answer there recommends that you investigate WIN32 journal hooks, thus sending WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK.

And another duplicate with what is reported to be a working snippet: [Clicking mouse by sending messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818192/clicking-mouse-by-sending-messages)

This discussion on MSDN indicates that it's not so easy using the raw mouse messages: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/vbide/thread/5352d3b8-4f9e-4a0a-8575-fdd592ae45f8.